# How to get started with sockets machine pack?

Tags: sails.js, treeline

What all do I need to get the node-machine [socketio's](http://node-machine.org/machinepack-sockets) blast to work on treeline? Do I need a socket.io client or does sails take care of that? I was assuming that the client socket is connected automatically by sails when sails.io.js is included then having a route that calls 'Send to all' and that all connected sockets would get something in the browsers console? Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any socket client capable of listening for events can be used to respond to notifications from machines in the sockets pack.  By default, when you use `treeline new` to start a new local Sails project that you'll link to Treeline, it'll include the Sails Socket Client module (`sails.io.js`).  Documentation for the module is [here](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client).

To do a quick test:

1. Add a "Send to all" machine to a route called `/hello` in Treeline, configured with the message name `news` and data `hello world!`
2. Start your linked local project using `treeline preview`, and open up the default home page at `http://localhost:1337`
3. Open up the Javascript console in your browser, and type `io.socket.on("news",function(data){console.log(data);})`.  This subscribes the client socket to the `news` event.
4. Open up another tab or window and go to `http://localhost:1337/hello`

In the first tab, you should see the string `hello world!` pop up in the console as the socket receives the `news` event.

Comment: Awesome! Worked just like that making sure to load a view with sails.io.js in it.

Comment: Thanks! do you have any suggestions on how to get it running by subscribing to a room and sending messages to a particular room? As, when using 'join room' machine. it asks for unique socket ids and whenever i try to get the socket ids from 'getRequestingSocketId' it throws a 500 error. Any help would be deeply appericiated!